# How do I make the same headers (or footers) for even and odd pages in the memoir class?

Tags: header-footer, memoir

I'm using the Memoir class for a 85 pg report in which I have to copy my client's format. It has 2 left-aligned isologotipes in the header, and 2 left-aligned addresses in the footer (plus some other things that seems irrelevant to this question).

[image: Layout of the headers and footers]

I already succeded in creating the header and footer for odd pages. I read the Memoir documentation but still can't find or understand *how to repeat the same header and footer for even pages too*.

My current MWE is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,openany,isopage]{memoir}
\usepackage{... many packages...}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor={Blue},urlcolor={Blue}}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\makepagestyle{plain}
\makeoddhead{plain}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{img/isologotype-1.pdf} ~~~~~~~~~~~ \includegraphics[height=1cm]{img/isologotype-2.pdf}}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{\miniscule \begin{tabular}{ll} Org 1 & Org 2 \\address 1  & address 2 \\tel 1, email 1 & tel 2, email 2 \\website 1 & website 2 \end{tabular}}{}{página \thepage\ de \pageref{LastPage}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\author{Author name}
\title{Report title}
\hypersetup{...}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents


\chapter{Síntesis}
\label{sec:orgheadline7}
Ipsum lorens

\section{Resultados generales}

\chapter{chapter's title}

...

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is my 1st question here, so please forgive me if I misunderstood or forgot some Stackexchange rule. :)

Comment: In essence you want the same header and footer on *all* pages. However, I assume you have `\chapter`s, right? Should they have a different page style?

Comment: it's good if you can add a minimal example of your code.

Comment: @Werner: yes, the same in all pages. However, I have sections, not chapters (I use org-mode as authoring environment).

Comment: @touhami: yes, I can put the relevant parts only... Do I do it in a comment, or editing the question? (sorry if it's obvious, I'n new on Sx).

Comment: @EduardoMercovich, edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating custom headers/footers in [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) is described in section **7.3 MAKING HEADERS AND FOOTERS** of the [`memoir` basic user manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf).

The following implements what you're after by creating a new page style `mypagestyle`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}% Just for this example

\newcommand{\headerleft}{%
  \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}\quad
  \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}}
\newcommand{\footerleft}{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
    Address A line 1 \\
    Address A line 2 \\
    Address A line 3
  \end{tabular}\quad
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
    Address B line 1 \\
    Address B line 2 \\
    Address B line 3
  \end{tabular}}

\makepagestyle{mypagestyle}
% \make<even/odd><head/foot>{<style>}{<left>}{<center>}{<right>}
\makeevenhead{mypagestyle}{\headerleft}% <left>
  {}{}% <center><right>
\makeoddhead{mypagestyle}{\headerleft}% <left>
  {}{}% <center><right>
\makeevenfoot{mypagestyle}{\footerleft}% <left>
  {}% <center>
  {Page \thepage{} of \thelastpage}% <right>
\makeoddfoot{mypagestyle}{\footerleft}% <left>
  {}% <center>
  {Page \thepage{} of \thelastpage}% <right>

\pagestyle{mypagestyle}% Set page style
\setheadfoot{47pt}{\footskip}% <headheight><footskip>

\begin{document}

\sloppy% Just for this example

\section{A section}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{A section}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{A section}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{A section}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{A section}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{A section}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{A section}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{A section}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{A section}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{A section}\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

<sub>The choice of a `47pt` value for `<headheight>` stemmed from a warning displayed during the first compilation.</sub>

Comment: your solution worked very well except for a mistake _I_ made before: I _do have chapters_, not only sections and subsections, so in every new chapter page, the header/footer is not the one specified. 

I found it looking at the source, so to eliminate the org-mode potential interference now I'm editing the latex file directly. Sorry. :(

I assume that the changes must be located in the section where you define the application of "mypagestyle"?

Comment: @EduardoMercovich: If you have `\chapter`s and you want the same pages style (headers/footers) there, you just have to add `\copypagestyle{chapter}{mypagestyle}` after you've defined the entire `mypagestyle` style. This will copy the `mypagestyle` over the `chapter` page style - executed with every `\chapter` command.

Comment: Thanks @Werner, it worked perfectly. I marked the answer and voted, but it won't be visible until I have more points. Now I understand better how the style definition works. Thanks again. :)